# Using method during copying object by spread operator in map method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to copy object and add a new property using spread operator in my Angular application. To add new property I want to call a method 'addNewProperty(name) that returns this property and its value. When I'm trying to call this method using spread operator, I get error about Unexpected token.

This is my code

```
this.files = files['results'].map(file => ({...file, this.addNewProperty(file.name)}));

addNewProperty(name) {
    return {
        extension: name.split('-')[1]
    };
}
```

On the other hand, when I use "traditional" Object.assign(), then everything is good

```
this.files = files['results'].map(file => Object.assign(file, this.addNewProperty(file.name)));
```

Could you explain me, why Object.assign() works correctly, while copying by {..., myMethod()} doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to spread the new object as well. Otherwise you have something without a key.

```
this.files = files['results'].map(file => ({...file, ...this.addNewProperty(file.name)}));
//                                                   ^^^
```